# Python: Intersection of two lists of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists `A` and a list of lists `B` where `A` and `B` have many identical sublists.

What is the best way to get the unique sublists out of `B` and into `A`?

```
A = [['foo', 123], ['bar', np.array(range(10))], ['baz', 345]]
B = [['foo', 123], ['bar', np.array(range(10))], ['meow', 456]]

=> A = [['foo', 123], ['bar', np.array(range(10))], ['baz', 345], ['meow', 456]]
```

I tried:

```
A += [b for b in B if b not in A]
```

But this gives me a `ValueError` saying to use `any()` or `all()`. Do I really have to test element by element for every sublist in `B` across every sublist in `A`?

```
ERROR: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback

Comment: Are `np.array` instances fully comparable?

Comment: The reason for the error is that you're effectively doing `np.arange(10) == np.arange(10)` which results in a boolean array instead of a single value (by very explicit design).  Normally you'd use sets for this, but numpy arrays aren't hashable. Therefore, it's easiest if you convert the arrays into immutable tuples, and each sub-list into either a tuple or a set. Then you can do "regular" set intersections.

Comment: Do you need to maintain list order or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use one of the many ways to uniquify a list or several lists either in order or not.

Here is a way to uniquify two list that does not maintain order:

```
>>> A=[1,3,5,'a','c',7]
>>> B=[1,2,3,'c','b','a',6]
>>> set(A+B)
set(['a', 1, 'c', 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 'b'])
```

Here is a way that does maintain order:

```
>>> seen=set()
>>> [e for e in A+B if e not in seen and (seen.add(e) or True)]
[1, 3, 5, 'a', 'c', 7, 2, 'b', 6]
```

The problem is that all elements must be hashable to use these methods:

```
>>> set([np.array(range(10)), 22])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

One way around this is to use the [repr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) of each element:

```
>>> set([repr(e) for e in [np.array(range(10)), 22]])
set(['22', 'array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])'])
```

Or a use a [frozenset](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
>>> set(frozenset(e) for e in [np.array(range(10)), np.array(range(2))])
set([frozenset([0, 1]), frozenset([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])])
```

In your case, the frozenset approach does not work on a list of lists:

```
>>> set(frozenset(e) for e in [[np.array(range(10)), np.array(range(2))],[np.array(range(5))
]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So you would need to use flattened lists.

If the repr of the sublist is definitive proof of its uniquity, you could do this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np

A = [['foo', 123], ['bar', np.array(range(10))], ['baz', 345]]
B = [['foo', 123], ['bar', np.array(range(10))], ['meow', 456]]

seen=OrderedDict((repr(e),0) for e in B)

newA=[]
for e in A+B:
    key=repr(e)
    if key in seen:
        if seen[key]==0:
            newA.append(e)
            seen[key]=1
    else:
        seen[key]=1
        newA.append(e)

print newA
# [['foo', 123], ['bar', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])], ['baz', 345], ['meow', 456]]
```

Since the `repr` function returns a string that can be used by `eval` function to recreate the list, that is pretty definitive test but I cannot say for absolutely sure. It depends on what is in your list.

For example, the repr of a lambda cannot recreate the lambda:

```
>>> repr(lambda x:x)
'<function <lambda> at 0x10710ec08>'
```

But the string value of `'<function <lambda> at 0x10710ec08>'` is still definitively unique because the `0x10710ec08` part is the address in memory of the lambda (in cPython anyways).

You could also do what I mentioned above -- use a flattened list in frozenset as a signature of what you have seen or not:

```
def flatten(LoL):
    for el in LoL:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el      
newA=[]    
seen=set()
for e in A+B:
    fset=frozenset(flatten(e))
    if fset not in seen:
        newA.append(e)
        seen.add(fset)

print newA        
# [['foo', 123], ['bar', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])], ['baz', 345], ['meow', 456]]
```

So if you have odd objects that are both unhashable and weird, non-unique `repr` string objects in A and B -- you are out of luck. Given your example, one of these methods should work though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
import numpy as np

A = [['foo', 123], ['bar', np.array(range(10))], ['baz', 345]]
B = [['foo', 123], ['bar', np.array(range(10))], ['meow', 456]]

res = set().update(tuple(x) for x in A).update(tuple(x) for x in B)
```

*except for* the np.array items, which are unhashable... not sure what to do with those.